Converting Cucumber Feature File Into An Executable Jar File
I currently run all my automations via Jenkins, however I was wondering if I would be able to extract my feature files into an executable Jar file so they could be executed locally by anyone. Is this possible? If not, is there any other way we can extract selenium automations into an executable file to be run? Thanks in advance.
I have tried using @RunWith(Cucumber.class) and feeding the @CucumberOptions in to run a certain tag in a gesture file, then building this as an artifact to run as a jar file. But this gave me a runtime error.

It is possible. But comes with a lot of complications and may not be worth the effort. The people running the tests can also clone the test project and run mvn test. Just like your CI does.
